# jQuery Validator plugin and radio buttons issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having an issue with the jQuery Validator plugin & radio buttons. I have a set of three `"lookingfor"` radio buttons... and I want to make sure at least one of those are checked.  Although regardless of what I do, I still get the message "This field is required." Any ideas?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" id="signupform" method="post">
        <label for="lookingfor" class="error"></label>
        <fieldset name="lookingfor">
            <input type="radio" name="lookingfor" value="female"/>
                <label for="female"><div class="sprite female" ></div></label>
            <input type="radio" name="lookingfor" value="male" />
                <label for="male"><div class="sprite male"></div></label>
            <input type="radio" name="lookingfor" value="other" />
                <label for="other"><div class="sprite other"></div></label> 
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="" />
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#signupform").validate({
            rules: {
                lookingfor:{ required: true }
            }
        });
        });
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is that you've duplicated your `radio` button group's `name`, `lookingfor`, inside of `<fieldset>`:

```
<fieldset name="lookingfor">
```

Remove this duplicate name and it works fine.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8qbUn/**

Answer (score -1):

Add checked inside one input so it will be the default selected radio button ?

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish?  If a radio button is already selected, then there's no point in this form validation rule.